# Configure a Firewall and a Startup Script with Deployment Manager template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, virtual-machine, firewall, startupscript

I want to configure a Firewall and a Startup Script with Deployment Manager template in .yaml file

Below are the steps I need to perform

1. A new Deployment Manager deployment has been created
2. The deployment includes a virtual machine that has an embedded startup-script
3. The virtual machine that has a startup-script also has a tag item
   called http
4. A firewall rule exists that allows port 80 (http)
   traffic and is applied using a tag with a value of http
5. The virtual machine responds to web requests using the Apache web server
6. Check that Deployment manager includes startup script and firewall resources

I'm facing problem with fifth step. All other steps complete successfully. However, fifth step shows error that "No VM responds to web requets". I can see the Apache Welcome page.

Comment: Can you add the .yaml, or at least the section of the .yaml that isn't meeting your expectations in the question?

Comment: Sir my .yaml is running well and even getting deployed. Here is the file-

Comment: resources:
- type: compute.v1.instance
  name: vm-test
  properties:
    zone: {{ properties["zone"] }}
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/zones/{{ properties["zone"] }}/machineTypes/f1-micro
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        diskName: disk-{{ env["deployment"] }}
        sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9

Comment: networkInterfaces:
    - network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/global/networks/default
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
    metadata:
      items:
      - key: startup-script
        value: |
          #!/bin/bash
          apt-get update
          apt-get install -y apache2
    tags:
      items:
      - http
    serviceAccounts:
    - email: 27225449300-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: scopes:
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
- type: compute.v1.firewall
  name: default-allow-http
  properties:
    network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/global/networks/default

Comment: targetTags: 
    - http
    allowed:
    - IPProtocol: tcp
      ports: 
      - '80'
    sourceRanges: 
    - 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: What is uploaded in parts is a jinja file

Comment: Can you  put the deployment yaml files formatted to your question, this is not clear.

Comment: it worked wid same settings....thanks for help though :)